# How do quarks interact in QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

In Electrodynamics the charges interact in a *extremely simple way*: same/different charges repel/atract each other. Is there any way of thinking the quarks interaction in a similar way?

I'd like some rule like "diferent colours atract", "same colours repel", "color and anticolour atract" or something like that but I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this helpful from [The Quantum Quark](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521089832) via Google Books:

[image]